# Piwik track Ecommerce: No Items

Tags: php, matomo

I try to track an e-commerce order with the piwik.php api.
I can see the order amount but no items.

ec_items — Items in the Ecommerce order. This is a JSON encoded array of items. Each item is an array with the following info in this order: item sku, item name, item category, item price, item quantity.

My json code for 1 order is:

```
[["sku","name","publisher","item-amount",1]]
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Your code must show similar like this:

> _paq.push(['addEcommerceItem','sku','ProductName','CategoryName','price','amount']);

Required parameters:

- addEcommerceItem
- sku

Recommended:

- price

Optional:

- ProductName
- CategoryName
- amount

Then you must create your order to specify the order details to Piwik server.

Comment: that is javascript, I need to do it with php.

Comment: Take a look this link. http://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/PHP-Piwik-Tracker

Comment: No I want use the piwik.php api and not the php-tracker.